# how to passing value from php to c like argument

Tags: php, c

Hi anyone I want to pass value from php to c by use php value as argument to run c program but c program can't be seen any value from php

This code of php :

```
    enter code here
<form action="create.php" method="post">
Create VM on website <br>
VM Name 
    <input type="text" name="vm_n" value="" />
VM Ram
    <input type="text" name="vm_r" value="" />
VM Virtual CPU
    <input type="text" name="vm_c" value="" />
VM File size 
    <input type="text" name="vm_fs" value="" />
VM File OS
    <input type="text" name="vm_b" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php
 //Check wihch Submit was clicked and pass from php
$vm_n[10]=$_POST['vm_n'];                                
$vm_r[5]=$_POST['vm_r'];
$vm_c[3]=$_POST['vm_c'];
$vm_fs[5]=$_POST['vm_fs'];
$vm_b=[8]$_POST['vm_b'];
if ($_POST['button1']) {
    echo "Creating VM.......";
    $last_line = system('/var/local/vmweb/create_vm install -n $vm_n -r $vm_r -c $vm_c -fs $vm_fs -b $vm_b', $retval);
    echo '
    </pre>
    <hr />Status Output: ' . $last_line . '
    <hr />Status Output: ' . $vm_n . '
    <hr />Status Output: ' . $vm_r . '
    <hr />Status Output: ' . $vm_c . '
    <hr />Status Output: ' . $vm_fs . '
    <hr />Status Output: ' . $vm_b . '
    <hr />Return value: ' . $retval;

} 
?>
and this code of C program : 
if (!(initsetuid())){
        exit(1);
    }
    // Check what command is asked
    if (argc==1)
    {       
        fprintf (stderr, "Missing Agument to Create VM command!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc==12 && strcmp(argv[1], OP_INSTALL)==0) {
        if (argc==12 && strcmp(argv[2], "-n")==0)   {
    printf("Argument is : %s Parameter is: %s \n", argv[2],argv[3]);        
    sprintf (vm_name,argv[3]);  
    //printf("vm_name is : %s \n",vm_name);
    }
```

I'm use if else to catch some argument on string

need you help me please !! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
system('/var/local/vmweb/create_vm install -n $vm_n -r $vm_r -c $vm_c -fs $vm_fs -b $vm_b', $retval);
```

You are using single quotes to surround variables in the string, PHP doesn't work that way. Use double quotes instead.

```
system("/var/local/vmweb/create_vm install -n $vm_n -r $vm_r -c $vm_c -fs $vm_fs -b $vm_b", $retval);
```

Also <strike>I think you've missed out an '=' here:</strike> You've put the '=' in the wrong place:

```
$vm_b=[8]$_POST['vm_b'];
```

Should be:

```
$vm_b[8] = $_POST['vm_b'];
```

**Wait a minute!**

I think all of this bit is wrong!

```
$vm_n[10]=$_POST['vm_n'];                                
$vm_r[5]=$_POST['vm_r'];
$vm_c[3]=$_POST['vm_c'];
$vm_fs[5]=$_POST['vm_fs'];
$vm_b=[8]$_POST['vm_b'];
```

You are creating arrays with the above code, and I don't believe that's really what you want..

Try this instead:

```
$vm_n = $_POST['vm_n'];                                
$vm_r = $_POST['vm_r'];
$vm_c = $_POST['vm_c'];
$vm_fs = $_POST['vm_fs'];
$vm_b = $_POST['vm_b'];
```

Comment: Yahoooo!!   Thank you a lot sir. now my program can be work. Thank you very much ^__^